# python socket return ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

i am programming a chat room project by python.Below is my server.py and client.py .When client is trying to connect to server ,it returns"in line8, client.connect((ip,port))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused".I have no idea why client canʼt connect to server while telnet can do so without a error.If you have any idea,please let me know,thank you.

server.py

```
import socket
#ip =socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ip="127.0.0.1"
port=8000
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((ip,port))
print("server ip address:"+ip)
server.listen(1)
conn,addr=server.accept()

user=addr[0]
print("[system]",user,"is online")
while True:
    message=str(conn.recv(1024), encoding='utf-8')
    if(not "quit()" in message):
        print(user+' : '+message)
    else:
        print("[system]"+user+" quit")
        conn.close()
        break
```

client.py

```
import socket


ip="127.0.0.1"
port=8000

client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((ip,port))


while(1):
    message=input("input:")
    
    client.sendall(message.encode())
    if(message=="quit()"):
        break
client.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1 :** [Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

> Coroutines declared with the async/await syntax is the preferred way
> of writing asyncio applications.

A running example:

```
import asyncio


async def f1():
    print('Hello')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def f2():
    print('World')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(f1())
asyncio.run(f2())
```

**Approach 2 :** [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading)

```
from time import sleep


def f1():
    print('Hello ')
    sleep(1)


def f2():
    print('World')
    sleep(1)


Thread(target=f1).start()
Thread(target=f2).start()
```

Unfortunately, due to the [Global interpreter lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) the functions will not be truly executed in parallel:

> A global interpreter lock (GIL) is a mechanism used in
> computer-language interpreters to synchronize the execution of threads
> so that only one native thread can execute at a time. An
> interpreter that uses GIL always allows exactly one thread to execute
> at a time, even if run on a multi-core processor.

**Approach 3:** [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an
> API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
> offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping
> the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.
> Due to this, the multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully
> leverage multiple processors on a given machine.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep


def f1():
    print('Hello ')
    sleep(1)


def f2():
    print('World')
    sleep(1)


p1 = Process(target=f1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=f2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiprocessing or threading, there are loads of videos about it on youtube if you want to look it up and try it out